# Why is this an improper overload?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-3.5, overloading

Error: cannot overload each other because they differ only by optional parameters.

One method has 3 parameters and the other has 4 parameters. What am I missing?

```
Protected Overloads Function updateResxNodes(ByVal keyCtrl As String, ByVal newValue As String, Optional ByVal newComment As String = "") As List(Of ResXDataNode)

    Dim resxNodesList As List(Of ResXDataNode) = getResourceData()
    For i As Integer = 0 To resxNodesList.Count - 1
        If resxNodesList.Item(i).Name = keyCtrl Then
            Dim name As String = resxNodesList.Item(i).Name
            Dim comment As String = resxNodesList.Item(i).Comment
            Dim newResxNode As ResXDataNode = New ResXDataNode(name, newValue)
            newResxNode.Comment = comment

            resxNodesList.RemoveAt(i)
            resxNodesList.Add(newResxNode)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return resxNodesList
End Function

Protected Overloads Function updateResxNodes(ByVal keyCtrl As String, ByVal newName As String, ByVal newValue As String, Optional ByVal newComment As String = "") As List(Of ResXDataNode)

    Dim resxNodesList As List(Of ResXDataNode) = getResourceData()
    For i As Integer = 0 To resxNodesList.Count - 1
        If resxNodesList.Item(i).Name = keyCtrl Then
            Dim name As String = resxNodesList.Item(i).Name
            Dim comment As String = resxNodesList.Item(i).Comment
            Dim newResxNode As ResXDataNode = New ResXDataNode(name, newValue)
            newResxNode.Comment = comment

            resxNodesList.RemoveAt(i)
            resxNodesList.Add(newResxNode)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return resxNodesList
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optional parameters are confusing the compiler on which function it should use.

Also, the compiler can't differentiate the newValue and newName parameters between the two functions because they are both strings in the second slot.

You aren't using newName in your second function-- does that belong there?

You might want to consider something like this:

```
Protected Overloads Function updateResxNodes(ByVal keyCtrl As String, ByVal newValue As String) As List(Of ResXDataNode)
  Return updateResxNodes(keyCtrl, newValue, String.Empty, String.Empty)
End Function

Protected Overloads Function updateResxNodes(ByVal keyCtrl As String, ByVal newValue As String, ByVal newName As String) As List(Of ResXDataNode)
  Return updateResxNodes(keyCtrl, newValue, newName, String.Empty)
End Function

Protected Overloads Function updateResxNodes(ByVal keyCtrl As String, ByVal newValue As String, ByVal newName As String, ByVal newComment As String) As List(Of ResXDataNode)
  Dim resxNodesList As List(Of ResXDataNode) = getResourceData()
  For i As Integer = 0 To resxNodesList.Count - 1
    If resxNodesList.Item(i).Name = keyCtrl Then
      Dim name As String = resxNodesList.Item(i).Name
      Dim comment As String = resxNodesList.Item(i).Comment
      Dim newResxNode As ResXDataNode = New ResXDataNode(name, newValue)
      newResxNode.Comment = comment
      resxNodesList.RemoveAt(i)
      resxNodesList.Add(newResxNode)
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  Return resxNodesList
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your optional parameters, which function would it use when you pass 3 parameters? The first one using the optional parameter or the second one disregarding it, using only the required ones and the optionals' default value?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is identification;

If you have two methods that only differ in signature because one parameter is optional, then the Compiler cannot know if you meant to call method A without the parameter or method B using the default value of the parameter.

You either need to rename one of the methods perhaps add the words 'ByValueOrDefault' to the method with the optional parameter, or make it non optional.